# Magento catalog search show zero result

Tags: catalogsearch

Magento search returns zero, while I print the query and execute in PHPMYADMIN - enough products are list.

1. Cache cleared
2. Re-indexed multiple times
   no solution, need help

Below is my query:

`SELECT e.*, price_index.price, price_index.tax_class_id, price_index.final_price, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS minimal_price, price_index.min_price, price_index.max_price, price_index.tier_price, cat_index.position AS cat_index_position FROM mg_catalog_product_entity AS e INNER JOIN mg_catalog_product_index_price AS price_index ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '2' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 INNER JOIN mg_catalog_category_product_index AS cat_index ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='2' AND cat_index.visibility IN(3, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '2'`

Thanks

Comment: Try to clear cache & re-indexing through command line :

Comment: May be its duplicate question of  [Magento search returning 0 results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714893/magento-search-returning-0-results-despite-products-enabled-and-proper-visibili)

Comment: yes, I was posted in stackexchange not magento.stackexchange. That's why I posted here too. Cache cleared from shell and admin, Nothing works.